# What does it mean for one function to be the limit of another

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, infinity

Consider two real valued functions
$F(a,x)=\frac{1}{a}+x^2$ and $G(x)=x^2$.

It is clear that as $a$ tends to infinity, $F$ tends to $G$; but what does that mean?

Shouldn't there be some kind of metric $M$, to measure the distance between $F$ and $G$ and to say that as a increases $M$ decreases and that there is no positive number that is the minimum value $M$ takes?

What kinds of metrics are there for problems like this?

Comment: This is point-wise convergence. That is, for each fixed $x$, we have $F(a,x) =\frac{1}{a} + x^2 \to x^2 = G(x)$ as $a \to \infty$.

Comment: I can only find the concept of pointwise convergence for sequences; has it been extended for continuous functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F$ tends to $G$ not only point-wise but uniformly.

Obviously, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $a$ such that

$$\sup_x |F(a,x)-G(x)|=\sup_x\left|\frac1a+x^2-x^2\right|=\frac1a<\varepsilon.$$

In this respect the measure of closeness is $\sup_x|F-G|$.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a geometric picture underlying this kind of convergence, specifically a **topology**. Specifically, the topology corresponding to pointwise convergence is the *point-open topology*: namely, the topology generated by sets of the form $$\{f: f(x)\in U\}$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ open.

(As zoli says, the limit you mention is in fact an instance of a stronger form of convergence. There are lots of examples of pointwise but not uniform convergence: e.g. ${x\over a}+x^2\rightarrow x^2$ pointwise, but not uniformly, as $a\rightarrow\infty$.)